# How to preserve the image as a matrix after calculating the mean of a list of images in python?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

My code failed to work on pca because of the dimension

I uploaded the images and then converted them to grayscale and `uint8` then I calculated the mean

This line does the mean for the images but here theimages become 2d

```
me_df= img_df.mean(axis=0)
```

Then, I selected a region of interest

```
 mask = np.zeros(me_df.shape, dtype=me_df.dtype)
 mask[roi_lower:roi_upper,roi_left:roi_right] = 1
 mask_df = mean_df * mask
```

Then I tried to convert it into 1d, but the code does not wrok as it is not 3d

I tried many things such as remove mask_df.shape[2] but the rest of the code. Did not work

The error messages are:

> maximum supported dimension for an ndarray is 32, found 640 or only
> integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

```
image_shape = mask_df[0].shape
frames_reshaped = mask_df.reshape([
    mask_df.shape[0],
    mask_df.shape[1]*mask_df.shape[2]
    ])

ncomp=4
pca = PCA(n_components=ncomp) 
pca.fit(test)
```

The PCA did not work because of the above errors

This code should show the image of the pca output with mean image

```
dd = pca.components_[pc_number-1].
     reshape(frames_reshaped)
mag = np.max(dd) - np.min(dd)
et = (dd-np.min(dd))/mag*255
plt.imshow(et, cmap="Greys_r")
```

Comment: if you have images in `mean_df` then don't assign `mean_df.mean()` to this variable `mean_df` but use different variable

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: @furas the problem is not related to the variable name. I changed that but the problem is still there

Comment: better create `minimal working code` (with example data) which we could copy and test.

Comment: @furas how to create this or send it on email